# Can we verify gap energy of a material by applying voltage across it?

Tags: insulator

Regarding the following statement:

“A material with fully occupied or empty energy bands is then an insulator. This is the case when the gap energy exceeds ~9eV, because for such gaps.”

So my question is if we have an insulator and if we know its gap energy is 10eV; does that mean it starts conducting current when we apply voltage across its terminals above 10V?

Comment: No. That's not what it means. It means the work function is \$10\: \text{eV}\$. Placing \$10\:\text{V}\$ across an insulator will produce a certain field ***gradient*** expressed in volts per meter. But a field gradient isn't an atomic quantum event. Between insulating atoms, it's unlikely to even be noticeable. Thermal jostling can, in a probabilistic way, achieve that. So can high energy photons. [\$10\:\text{eV}\$ photons are \$124\:\text{nm}\$ (strong UV.)]

Comment: Not on the bulk level. That applies at the level of a single atom, which doesn't have terminals. If you take a very thin sheet of insulator (say 0.1mm thick) with a metalised layer on each side, there are probably a million atoms between those layers (terminals). You'll need a lot more than 10V to get it to conduct.

Answer (score 0):

Not that way.

The bandgap can be measured with the voltage generated by controlled optical energy or thermal energy and is measured by the incremental slope of log saturation current for a fixed low reverse voltage for step increments of temperature.

You measure the diode reverse saturation current in uA in 10'C increments with a low reverse voltage from 0.2 to 2V.

You apply a small reverse voltage to achieve the constant saturation current vs temperature curve. One could heat up the diode in water from say 40'C to 70'C and plot the slope of log Is vs 5036/T ['K] to get bandgap  ∆E.

log Is = Constant – 5036 ∆E/T

or ∆E = slope of Log (Is)*T/5036  for T['K]